# Add custom marker to Mapbox map

Tags: javascript, jquery, mapbox, mapbox-gl-js

I using mapbox in my project

I was using mapbox.js 
and make my map with custom markers like this

```
 $(function() { 
  const token = '*********';
  let myLatlng = L.latLng(<%= @hotel.lat %>,<%= @hotel.lng %>);
  L.mapbox.accessToken = token;
  let map = L.mapbox.map('map-canvas', 'mapbox.streets')
  .setView(myLatlng, 14);

  let marker = new L.marker(myLatlng,{
    icon: L.icon({
        iconUrl: '//chart.googleapis.com/chart?chst=d_map_pin_icon&chld=home|EBCB2D'
      })
  }).addTo(map);
  });
```

And I was changing icon of marker like this

```
  icon: L.icon({
        iconUrl: '//chart.googleapis.com/chart?chst=d_map_pin_icon&chld=home|EBCB2D'
      })
```

I wondering if MapBox GL JS have any shorthand method like rhis to change it?

Comment: You can use `addImage`: https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/add-image/

Comment: Or you can use a GL JS Marker by creating an img element.

Answer (score 7):

To spell out the two comments given, there are two different ways to add custom images to a map:

#### Using symbol layers

A symbol layer exists within the map and can be used to visualise a data source.

First, use `loadImage()` to fetch the image URL:

```
map.loadImage('https://example.com/image.png', function(error, image) {
    if (error) throw error;
```

Then, use `addImage()` to convert the fetched image into an icon for use in the map:

```
   map.addImage('pin', image);
```

Finally, use that icon on a layer:

```
   map.addLayer({ id: 'mypin', type: 'symbol', paint: { 'icon-image': 'pin' });
```

Full example: https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/add-image/

### Using Markers

Alternatively, you can use a Marker. This exists above the map and doesn't interact with the data in it.

First, create the DOM element for the image:

```
var el = document.createElement('div');
el.className = 'marker';
el.style.backgroundImage = 'url(https://example.com/icon.png)';
el.style.width = '20px';
el.style.height = '20px';
```

Next, create a Marker object based on this element, and add it to the map:

```
new mapboxgl.Marker(el)
    .setLngLat(mylatlng)
    .addTo(map);
```

Full example: https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/custom-marker-icons/

Comment: Which one is better in terms of performance?

Answer (score 0):

## I highly recommend to resolve this problem in this way:

#### First create the element to replace the old marker:

```
const customMarker = document.createElement('div');
customMarker.style.backgroundImage = 'url(../../../assets/images/pin.svg)';
customMarker.style.backgroundSize = 'cover';
customMarker.style.backgroundPosition = 'center';
customMarker.style.width = '27px';
customMarker.style.height = '41px';
```

#### Then create the marker object with an option object as argument, with the next properties:

```
 const marker = new mapboxgl.Marker({
    anchor: 'bottom',
    element: customMarker,
  })
   .setLngLat([this.lng, this.lat])
   .addTo(map);
```

Because, if you resolve this in other way the marker will be placed almost randomly in your map and it would make the ux looks bad

###### Example with my solution:

[image: example]

###### Example with other solution:

[image: example2]

For more details check this part of the documentation:
[Docs](https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/api/markers/#marker)

Answer (score 0):

You can easily use like this. This code is find from mapbox website

```
var marker = new mapboxgl.Marker({
  element: createCustomMarkerElement('./assets/images/heart.png'),
})
.setLngLat([location.lng, location.lat])
.addTo(map);
```

The customMarker function is

```
function createCustomMarkerElement(imagePath) {
    const el = document.createElement('div');
    const width = 50;
    const height = 55;
    el.className = 'marker';
    el.style.backgroundImage = 'url(' + imagePath + ')';
    el.style.width = `${width}px`;
    el.style.height = `${height}px`;
    el.style.backgroundSize = '100%';
    return el;
 }
```

Finaly use can use some styles like this

```
<style>
.marker {
  display: block;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 50%;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 0;
}
</style>
```